# Reconstructing a Hash, naming and replacing issue

Tags: ruby, hashmap, hashtable

I'm receiving a string-based `Hash` looking like the following:

```
"data"=>{"uno"=>"alfa", "dos"=>"beta"}
```

I want to reconstruct it, such that it has the following *object structure* and *naming*:

```
beta: {uno: "alfa"}
```

I'm getting stuck already at taking an inner value and converting it to a key. Any help to reach the above would be much appreciated.

**Update**
There are several things going on here and I regret doing *one* question out of it. But now as it's already out in the wild, I'll try my best to explain further.
1. The keys need to be converted to symbols
2. The pair `"dos"=>"beta"` should be inverted
3. The inverted key of the above mentioned pair should take over the role (from `"data"`) as key for the whole `Hash`

Ps. As I seem to have massively failed in clearly explaining my question, feel free to downvote.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your reconstruction ! Can you explain exactly what you want to do with your initial hash ?

Comment: Are those keys (uno, dos) fixed values? Otherwise, which is the logic behind "inverting" beta and data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code:

```
h.reduce({}) { |hh,v| hh[ v[1][ 'dos' ].to_sym ] = { :uno => v[1][ 'uno' ] } ; hh }
# => {:beta=>{:uno=>"alfa"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert the key from string to symbol, use :

```
hash.inject({}){|h,(k,v)| h[k.to_sym] = v; h}
```

Doing so will return : `{data: {uno: "alfa", dos: "beta"}}`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

The simple way convert to a Ruby hash would be to `eval` the string, BUT that is *dangerous*. So we can use a safer way:

```
>> s = '"data"=>{"uno"=>"alfa", "dos"=>"beta"}'
=> ""data"=>{"uno"=>"alfa", "dos"=>"beta"}"

>> require 'json'
=> true

>> t2 = "{#{s}}".gsub('=>', ':')
=> "{"data":{"uno":"alfa", "dos":"beta"}}"

>> h1 = JSON.parse(t2).to_hash
=> {"data"=>{"uno"=>"alfa", "dos"=>"beta"}}

>> {:data => h1["data"].inject({}){|h,(k,v)| h[k.to_sym] = v; h}}
=> {:data=>{:uno=>"alfa", :dos=>"beta"}}
```

Also it would be better if you give some more examples of what behaviour you expect.